# UITextField subclass used in view controller initialized from xib file : init(coder) never gets called

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitextfield

I have a simple view controller containing a custom `UITextField` subclass:

```
final class MyVC: UIViewController {
    // MARK: View Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: TextField!
    // ...

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: "MyVC", bundle: .main)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
}

class TextField: UITextField {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    override class func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }
}
```

I have added breakpoints in every of these `TextField` methods, but none ever gets called. I have double-checked that the textField `IBOutlet` in `MyVC` xib file is a `TextField` component, correctly linked to the variable, and so on. I have absolutely no idea what's causing this.

[image]

[image]

Thank you for your help

Comment: Shouldn’t it be `overripe func awakeFromNib()` instead of `override class func awakeFromNib()`?

Comment: `MyVC` is a **XIB**, not a controller in your Storyboard? How are you loading it? Quick test with `print("TextField", #function)` in each, and I see this in the debug console: `TextField init(coder:)` / `TextField awakeFromNib()` / `TextField layoutSubviews()` / `TextField layoutSubviews()`